# Not able to use standard regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to C# and I am trying to reuse this regex from this question but unfortunately, its not giving me any results. The C# code is below:

```
string pattern = @"^(((ht|f)tp(s?))\:\/\/)?(www.|[a-zA-Z].)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|edu|gov|mil|net|org|biz|info|name|museum|us|bd|ca|uk)(\:[0-9]+)*(\/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$";

var linkParser = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var rawString = @"www.antilogvacations.com bhxbldsa 
                https://www.sample.com
                http://www.sample.com/xyz
                www.sample.com
                www.sample.com/xyz/#/xyz
                sample.com
                blah www.sample.com blah mofiz.com";
MatchCollection matches = linkParser.Matches(rawString);
foreach (Match m in matches)
   Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

The same regex is working fine on : https://regex101.com

I do not understand what I may be doing wrong.

Edit 1: The regex is also not able to capture the URL in text, for example the last line in the rawString.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\;\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+`  is painful but I guess it still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. add `RegexOptions.Multiline`
2. get rid of the indentation on the left of the values - `^foo` doesn't match a `foo` that starts 12 characters in.
3. Add optional '\r' to the end of regex for multi-line support.

so:

```
string pattern = @"^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www.)?(?!.*(ftp|http|https|www.))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)+((\/)[\w#]+)*(\/\w+\?[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+(&[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=\w+)*)?(\r)?$";

var linkParser = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var rawString = @"www.antilogvacations.com bhxbldsa 
https://www.sample.com
http://www.sample.com/xyz
www.sample.com
www.sample.com/xyz/#/xyz
sample.com
www.sample.com
mofiz.com"; // NO spaces to the left of these
```

Comment: In the output I am still getting only: mofiz.com. After the fixes, shouldn't it detect all the URLs?

Comment: @user3667569 hmmm; agreed - one sec...; edit: it is something to do with that last match

Comment: It is due to the `\r\n` endings, you must add `\r?` before `$`.

Comment: Bingo - That's fixed it Wiktor!

Comment: Just one last thing: if I put two emails together in the same line, it doesn't detect those `www.sample.com mofiz.com` , I tried to modified the regex by putting an optional `\s` but it didn't work. Can someone help?

Comment: @user3667569 you'd have to be more specific  - what does "two emails together" look like? where did you try to put a `\s`? how did adding that `\s` repeat the match?

Comment: As in two emails in the same line : updated the question.

Comment: @user3667569 you know these aren't emails, and this regex isn't about processing emails, right?

Comment: Sorry yes, I meants URLs, not emails.

Comment: @user3667569 in your edit: what are the two things you think should match? do you mean the `www.sample.com` and `mofiz.com` from the `blah www.sample.com blah mofiz.com` string? if so: that is *nothing like* the regex pattern you're using, and you'd need to start from first principles in terms of what should / shouldn't match

Comment: You are right, its that what I want. I think that's a different question then, right?

Comment: @user3667569 yes, that's quite a bit different